# When should x.509 certificate validity should be checked?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

we want to use openssl lib in our communications with certificates for mutual authentication.
we have setup a CA, with subca and certificates for clients & server.
upon connection it is easy to check the certificate validity: starting date, expiration date, signature, CRL.

but let say the communication once establish drag on and one of the certificates expires, should the communication be closed ?

What if a certificate becomes compromised ? we will have the CRL updated, should we check the CRL for every packet ?

Checking the expiration date should be fairly fast, so could be ok to do on every read/write.

Checking the CRL is a bit more involved and I think could slow down communication a lot.
this is why I wonder what should be done ?

some of our certificates can last for a year, which could means that CRL could grow a lot if many certificates becomes compromised!

Comment: In short: the certificate is used to make sure that the SSL session is with the expected party and not some man in the middle attacker. So it needs to be checked at the beginning of the SSL session, i.e. a whenever a full handshake is done. Since an established SSL session is integrity protected a man in the middle tampering with the connection would be detected - so one does not again need to verify the certificate during the SSL session.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich during the session there could be renegociation. can there be new certificates exchange then ?